# Check if horizontally overflowing element is no longer scrollable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So im trying to detect if a div is fully horizontally scrolled to the left. If so, I'd like to hide the scroll button, (left or right one).
So the structure is simple,
React

```
const overflowref = useRef()
const toggleScroll = (sign) => {
 if(sign==='negative'){
    overflowref.current.scrollLeft -= 100
    return
  }
 overflowref.current.scrollLeft += 100
}
```

HTML

```
<div style={{width: '400px', overflowX: 'scroll'}} ref={overflowref}>
 <i className='fal fa-chevron-left' onClick={()=> toggleScroll('negative')}></i>
 <img style={{width: '100px'}}/>
 <img style={{width: '100px'}}/>
 <img style={{width: '100px'}}/>
 <i className='fal fa-chevron-right' onClick={()=> toggleScroll()}></i>
</div>
```

So basically, I wanna get  a boolean value once the max scroll has been reached on either side.